# Not able to log back into my Windows machine after Hyper-v installation

Tags: windows, hyper-v

I have a Windows 10 machine. Recently I have installed Hyper-V 2016 server on my machine. From then whenever I start my system I only see a blue screen with various commands. I do not see any other thing other than that. Now how can I go back to my normal Windows machine?

See this image for reference:

[image: See this image for reference]

Comment: I suspect that since this is not about programming, it would be better on Super User.

Answer (score 0):

you **had** Windows 10 installed on your machine now you have Microsoft Hyper-V Server 2016.

I assume you downloaded an ISO and installed that one. Whereas within Windows 10 you only have to activated a feature called `Hyper-V`.

Grap your latest Backups and install Windows 10 back onto your machine.

KR

Guenther